# Codeigniter: Array Submission Validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having a problem on validating using `empty()` on codeigniter.

It seemed that it always returns true, empty or not.

```
<input type="text" name="contactname[]" value="<?php echo set_value('contactname[]');?>">
```

Model:

```
if(empty($this->input->post('contactname'))) {
           return TRUE;
      } else {
            return FALSE;
          }
```

I really don't know what's the cause of this issue.

Comment: Use isset() function isset ($this->input->post('contactname')) in if condition

Comment: set_value('contactname[]'), this function may cause the problem. Maybe contactname[] becomes empty on form submission as u don't pass any value as second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$contactname = $this->input->post('contactname')
if(empty($contactname)) {
           return TRUE;
      } else {
            return FALSE;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$contact_name = $this->input->post('contactname[]');

if($contact_name != null) 
{
   return TRUE;
} else{
       return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can use "null !== func()" instead) in...` I'm having that error

Comment: eny error?? what is the result off ` $contact_name`

Comment: no error. but, still, the problem it is always returning TRUE, even though `$this->input->post('contactname[]')` has no value or is null.

Comment: what is the result  of `$this->input->post('contactname')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105324/discussion-between-naseeba-c-and-aaron-alfonso).

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter provides a comprehensive form validation and data prepping class that helps minimize the amount of code you'll write. You can load library like this in your controller or model :

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

To set validation rules you will use the set_rules() function like this :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('contactname[]', 'Contact name', 'required');
```

So you need to update your code with given below code -

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('contactname[]', 'Contact name', 'required');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    echo validation_errors();
}
else
{
   // wrire you code here after validation run success
}
```

For for reference see this link -
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: Yes yes. I know the form validation. I wasn't talking about form validation though

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if (count($this->input->post('contactname')) > 0)
           return TRUE;
          } else {
          return FALSE;
          }
```